# Can't Install image from PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Keep being thrown an error.

My import statement is:

```
from PIL import Image
```

The error is:

```
C:\Users\User\anaconda\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torchvision\io\image.py:11: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: Could not find module 'C:\Users\User\anaconda\envs\deeplearning\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\image.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}")
```

I'm using a conda environemnt. PLs help

Comment: Exactly how did you install this?  PIL requires `libjpeg` and `zlib`.  Some installation methods bring those in, some don't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.